# Refactoring: How to efficiently render json in Rails update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, dry

How can I refactor this code so I don't repeat the json objects over and over again when they use the same basic format?  I'm still a bit uncomfortable with Ruby on Rails so I'm unsure of the best way to approach this.

```
  # PUT /users/:user_id/profile/:id
  def update
    if request.xhr?
      profile = current_user.profile

      if params[:profile].blank?
        render :json => { :error => "There was no profile data passed in so your profile could not be saved." }, 
               :status => :unprocessable_entity
      else
        if profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
          render :json => { :interests => 
                              simple_format(h(profile.interests), :class => "pbs tl"),
                            :favorite_music =>
                              simple_format(h(profile.favorite_music), :class => "pbs tl"),
                            :favorite_movies =>
                              simple_format(h(profile.favorite_movies), :class => "pbs tl"),
                            :favorite_books =>
                              simple_format(h(profile.favorite_books), :class => "pbs tl"),
                            :favorite_foods =>
                              simple_format(h(profile.favorite_foods), :class => "pbs tl") },
                 :status => :ok
        else
          render :json => { :error => get_errors_for_class(profile).to_sentence }, 
                 :status => :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

---

**Update**: I modified the original answer a little and it works for me.  Here's my modification:

```
  # within profile.rb
  # create a hash of profile attributes
  def html_to_hash
    %w{interests favorite_music favorite_books favorite_foods}.inject({}) do |hash, property|
      hash[property] = simple_format(h(self.send(property)), :class => 'pbs tl')
      hash
    end    
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the data in that huge hash a method of `Profile`.

```
class Profile
  def to_hash
    [:interests, :favorite_music, :favorite_books, :favorite_foods].inject({}) do |h, prop|
      h[prop] = simple_format(h(self.send(:prop)), :class => 'pbs tl')
      h
    end
  end
end
```

then

```
# PUT /users/:user_id/profile/:id
  def update
    if request.xhr?
      profile = current_user.profile

      if params[:profile].blank?
        render :json => { :error => "There was no profile data passed in so your profile could not be saved." }, 
               :status => :unprocessable_entity
      else
        if profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
          render :json => profile.to_hash,
                 :status => :ok
        else
          render :json => { :error => get_errors_for_class(profile).to_sentence }, 
                 :status => :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I had to modify your code a bit to get it to work since it kept saying "prop wasn't a valid method".  I posted the modified portion to my original question.  Thanks for getting me on the right track!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `as_json` method on your Profile class that returns the same hash and then just do `render :json => profile`. Another alternative is to plug in [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and tell it which attributes you want to serialize and how.